# Algorithm complexity calculations

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am beginning to learn how to code in c.
Currently, I am trying to implement a program that will display output similar to this:

{
Welcome to CSE  Sorting System

---

Please enter your array of size :
Please select one of the following sorting algorithms:
 1 - Bubble Sort
 2 - Insertion Sort
 3 - Selection Sort
 4 - Quick Sort
Your choice:

Your array has been sorted using Selection Sort in x steps.

Array after sorting: }

My program is mostly complete, but I am having trouble determining how to calculate the number of x steps that were used in the sorting process.  How do I deduce the number of "steps" that the algorithm used?

Comment: Count how many swaps you make with each algorithm?

Comment: @GWW, right, but wouldn't the number of swaps be dependent on the order that the numbers were entered into the array?  i.e.  if they were entered in ascending order, 0 swaps would be made.

Comment: @keyhammer: Yes, exactly. (At least, for bubble-sort. The others work differently.) That's why we usually discuss the "worst-case complexity" of a sorting algorithm, which is the maximum number of steps used for *any* input of a given length.

Comment: @ruakh the swaps aren't the dominant factor in sorting; *comparisons* are.

Comment: @WhozCraig so if comparisons are the dominant factor, would each sorting step size be constant as long as the array size is constant, independent of the order that the elements were entered?

Comment: @WhozCraig: True, but my comment stands. :-)

Comment: @keyhammer No. Quicksort, for example, can easily degenerate into an O(N^2) comparison complexity on a perfectly sorted list. Mergsesort, on the other hand, will perform in O(NlogN) on the same list. Partitioning algorithms that are value-determinant in their paritioning must vary in their runtime complexity, which is precisely why the algorithm analysis in both the general case, and the worst case, is so important. The value-indeterminant algorithms (bubble-sort, merge sort, etc.) will not change, but have additional pluses and minuses.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an interesting, but somewhat challenging problem to solve. A 'step' is pretty abstract in and of itself.

Say I have some arbitrary sorting function:

```
void lameSort(int* array, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if (array[i] == 5) {
      int tmp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[i - 1];
      array[i - 1] = tmp;
    }
  }
}
```

What exactly would you define a 'step' to be? You could say

- initializing the index = 1 step
- comparing every array element with 5 = n steps (length of array)
- initializing the temp variable = 1 step
- ... etc

You would have to somehow keep count of each of these 'steps'.

And also, people don't usually measure algorithmic complexity in terms of exact steps. They express running time / storage complexity in terms of Big-O notation, with the highest order polynomial being the running time.

Comment: Your "allocating" is a compile-time operation and eqauls to zero steps

Comment: Whoops -- meant to say initializing.

Answer (score 0):

The Complexity of programs can not be compared by simply counting the total number of instruction executed by each program. You need Asymptotic analysis, Amortized analysis etc to analyse the complexity of algorithms. In Asymptotic analysis the **limiting behavior** of the  algorithms are analyzed.

Limiting behavior is effective only for **n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>**. The Asymptotic Big-O complexity of Quick Sort is **O(n log n)** which is less than the complexity of Bubble Sort with **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**. But for arbitrary values of n < n<sub>0</sub> Bubble Sort may out perform Quick Sort even in the average case. Thus your method of counting the total number of instructions executed to compare programs may not yield proper results.

Answer (score 0):

For Complexity Notations , go [here](http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/LN250_Weiss/L02-BigOh.htm)

For Complexity Calculations Examples , go [here](http://faculty.simpson.edu/lydia.sinapova/www/cmsc250/LN250_Weiss/L03-BigOh.htm)

Both the lessons are explained in a very simple and easy language